# W3 validation stray start tag html

Tags: html, validation

After W3 validation, I am getting the following error, what should I do?

> Error: Stray start tag html.
>   From line 174, column 2; to line 174, column 68

```
iner">↩ ↩   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">↩<meta
```

This is the very first line of my website:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=latin1_swedish_ci" />
<!-- <?php bloginfo('charset'); ?> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Comment: from the look of things, you have a few linebreaks somewhere before your opening HTML tag. Are you sure those are the first lines (in terms of numbering) in the file?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure, check this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/OSh3uOS

Comment: These lines are present in header.php

Comment: can you screenshot the code in an IDE please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pfFcCEA

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IsFmLFI